# OpenJDK vs oracle

Tags: linux, jvm, java

From what I see oracle jdk isn't present in all major linux distros.
There's only openjdk version. So if you want to use oracle, the only option is to download jdk from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and configure it manually.

Openjdk and oracle version are almost identical except some parts (some closed source third party components like a graphics rasterizer, some open source third party components).

Which jvm servers use in production and how they intall and update jvm/jdk if it's oracle 
version? (With openjdk it's easy with package manager) 
Which jvm/jdk do you use in dev and prod in linux?

It seems to me like java environment is a second class citizen in linux.

Comment: OpenJDK **is** Oracle, but with different license...

Answer (score -1):

> Which JVM servers are used in production and how do
>   they install and update JVM/JDK if it's Oracle version?

The Oracle JVM is used in PROD. For PROD (and not only),
usually manual installations take place.

> Which JVM/JDK do you use in DEV and PROD in linux?

Again the Oracle one (for both DEV and PROD).

*The above answers are based simply on my experience

(that is I don't claim these to be some best practices).*

Comment: interesting, twitter uses openjdk https://engineering.twitter.com/university/videos/twitter-scale-computing-with-openjdk

Comment: According to http://openjdk.java.net/ OpenJDK and OracleJDK share a large code chunk.